# How to Run GIF and load Dll simultaneously in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, xaml

I am learning `Wpf` from scratch. I created Splash Window that should start once When application start. Splash Window have *`*One dog running GIF**.`
In Background my `dll` getting load. My problem is If I don't use `**Task.Delay(1000)**` or `**Thread.Sleep(1000)**.` My **GIF** won't work.
If I use `**Task.Delay(1000)**` or `**Thread.Sleep(1000)**` then my GIF works but make my program execution slow because after 1 sec as I set in **Delay(1000)** or **Sleep(1000)** my Program begun Started and my GIF getting stopped.

What i want is Both(My GIF and Application Execution Should Run Simultaneously)
and after all DLL got Load login screen will be show

**Splash Screen .Xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="DemoProject.SplashWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PetGalaxy_GED"
     xmlns:gif="http://wpfanimatedgif.codeplex.com"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    ResizeMode="NoResize" AllowsTransparency="True"  Background ="Transparent" Opacity="1" WindowStyle="None" WindowStartupLocation = "CenterScreen"
    Title="GalaxyEnterpriseDesktop" Height="300" Width="600">

<Border Background="#F7F7F7" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="22,22,22,22">
    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Grid Height="auto" Margin="170,0,228,0">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Text="Loading" Grid.Column="0" Margin="38,19,5,19" FontSize="16" FontWeight="SemiBold"/>
            <!--<ProgressBar Minimum="0" Maximum="100" Height="10" Background="Transparent" Width="100" Foreground="Black" Name="pbStatus" IsIndeterminate="True" Grid.Column="1" Margin="4,29,-4,20" />-->
            <Image Width="100" Height="50" gif:ImageBehavior.RepeatBehavior="50x" gif:ImageBehavior.AnimatedSource="..\Images\RunningDog.gif" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="0.61,0.465" Margin="65,-7,35,0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
</Border>
```

**Splash Screen.Xaml.cs**

```
public partial class SplashWindow : Window
{
    public SplashWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }
}
```

I am showing My Splash Window From

**App.Xaml.cs**

```
var splashScreen = new SplashWindow();
        //this.MainWindow = splashScreen;
        //this.MainWindow.Close();
        splashScreen.Show();
       // System.Threading.Thread th = new System.Threading.Thread();
        //in order to ensure the UI stays responsive, we need to
        //do the work on a different thread
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            //simulate some work being done
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);

            //since we're not on the UI thread
            //once we're done we need to use the Dispatcher
            //to create and show the main window
            this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
                //initialize the main window, set it as the application main window
                //and close the splash screen
                var mainWindow = new Views.Common.LogIn();
                this.MainWindow = mainWindow;
                    mainWindow.Show();
                splashScreen.Close();
            });
        });
```

Comment: Please show how you load the DLL's. In a BackgroundThread?

Comment: Actually that i can not show you because its showing in Output Window.

Comment: I am getting this Exception while loading both

Comment: The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this.

Comment: private async void LoadImageData()
        {
            LogIn getLoginWindow;
            await Task.Delay(2000).ContinueWith(_ =>
            {
                getLoginWindow = new LogIn();
                getLoginWindow.Show();
            });
        }